# Adding UIScrollView to view and sending it to the back

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have added few UI components using Storyboard (UILabel, UIImageView). I am trying to put UIScrollView in this view, below all other elements:

Here is my code right at the end of `-viewWillAppear` method (code from my View Controller):

```
UIScrollView *scroll =  [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;

[self.view addSubview:scroll];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:scroll];
```

The reason why I need a `UIScrollView` is large amount of text in `detailsLabel` - I'm attaching code I use for handling this label programatically:

```
    detailsLabel.text = @"Some long text taken from databse";
    [detailsLabel sizeToFit];
    detailsLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    detailsLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

What I am doing wrong? How do I put UIScrollView below all other elements of my main view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've followed the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10807589/963881) and it worked great: I've changed the Custom Class in Identity Inspector from UIView to UIScrollView and added this line to my `-viewDidLoad` in the View Controller file:

```
[(UIScrollView *)self.view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 700)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UIScrollView *scroll =  [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;

[self.view insertSubview:scroll atIndex:0];

...

[self.view insertSubview:detailsLabel atIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in `ViewDidLoad` . Then add the labels after you have added the `UIScrollView` to the self.View in the `ViewDidLoad` itself. So by default the `UIScrollView` would be added on the self.View and then your label. Now you can either add the label on the scrollview or onto the self.view .

Answer (score 0):

Option One:

Declare detailsLabel in .h:

```
IBOutlet UILabel * detailsLabel; // MAP IT WITH NIB or STORYBOARD
```

give it property and Synthesise in .m.

here in viewDidLoad  declare:

```
UIScrollView *scroll =  [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:scroll];

[scroll addSubview:detailsLabel];
```

// IT SHOULD WORK.

Option two:

If you have large amount of text to display, then you can also use UITextView, it has inbuilt scrollview. And you can also set its text edit property.